# Azure Web API vs. Mobile Services

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

What are the main differences when using

- Azure Web API (technically using Azure Web Site Module) - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/rest-service-using-web-api/#bkmk_createmvc4app VS
- Azure Mobile Services - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-ios/

I'd like to build a webservice that will be used by both mobile and web client. Which should I use?

Comment: Would need more information to answer your question...Azure Web APIs provide a lot more control to create a full REST/Hypermedia API.  Azure Mobile Services are much quicker to start, but only really provide simple data access and authentication mechanisms (i.e. Facebook).  For a simple demo/simple app..Mobile Services are the way to go.  For a full blown API that works on mobile, desktop, servers etc...Web APIs are the way to go, but it requires more work.

Answer (score 7):

I think the Mobile Service is mainly focus on quick mobile service development especially for those data oriented. If you want to create a mobile application quickly, with CRUD against your data on cloud, with push notification out-of-box, mobile service might be a good choice.

But if you need complex server side logic, Azure Web Site could be better. You can create your own API with your own logic by using ASP.NET MVC WebAPI, Node.js, etc.