# mobile service API or .net Web API for querying azure SQL data

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-mobile-services

I am going to develop a mobile app, its bit of social kind of app.

For data, I am planning to use Azure SQL for hierarchical data and Azure Storage for images etc.

Now for user authentication, I want my users to log in using oAuth providers such as Facebook/google/live etc rather than developing a user authentication of my own.

So for oAuth, I am planning to use Azure Mobile Services.

The thing I am not clear is after I authenticate user using Mobile Services, how I go to query the user's data that is in Azure SQL . Should I use the APIs that I can write in Node.js from Mobile Services or should I develop a WebAPI project to talk to data.

Using Mobile Service's node.js API looks easy and simplest way, but the apprehension I have with querying data from Mobile Service is it allows to query the tables that are in its own schema. If I wish to have some tables in some other logical schema, I won't be able to query it from Mobile services. Is my understanding correct here?

.net WEBAPI will be my preferred way of talking to database,but if I write a WebAPI, how do I get user's Identity carried from Mobile Services to WebAPI.

if someone can point me to some example/sample of using using Web API and Mobile Services together, will appreciate

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Services would allow you to access table's outside of its schema, although it is more work.  You can use the MSSQL object to talk to additional schemas.  See: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#TSQL

The new .NET runtime, currently in preview, also has support for using multiple data sources.

Comment: thanks for that link, will go thru 
<br/>
meanwhile looking at related questions([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782613/azure-mobile-services-and-azure-web-site-integration?) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236617/azure-web-api-vs-mobile-services) ), I'm bit skeptical using MobileServices to build service API. One of the responses in these questions say using server-side mobile services API is good for small scale data requirements, but not recommended for larger databases. Should I consider these responses seriously or can these be ignored considering bit dated now?

Comment: so , the question is - is server-side mobile services API recommended for large scale data, with some moderately-complex business logic?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep azure mobile services for authentication. You can then create your full schema in SQL where your user is nothing more than the userid from mobile services.

In code you end up with this user id after authentication. From that point forward everything is in SQL.